# Exibir erro específico ! java.sql.SQLException'

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Olá

Estou como seguinte código:

```
<c:set var="exception" value="${requestScope['java.sql.SQLException']}"/>
    <p class="alert alert-danger"><b>Ops!</b> Erro: <br><br>
 <!-- Stack trace -->

    <jsp:scriptlet>
      // exception.printStackTrace();
      exception.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(out));
    </jsp:scriptlet>
   </p>
```

Só que o erro vem muita coisa:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20999: Aluno já cadastrado anteriormente
 ORA-06512: em "DBAADV.TRG_CURSO_INSCRICAO", line 8 
 ORA-04088: erro durante a execução do gatilho 'DBAADV.TRG_CURSO_INSCRICAO' 
 ORA-06512: em "DBAADV.PROC_INSCRICAO", line 13 
 ORA-06512: em line 1 at 
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) at 
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) at 
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059) at 
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522) at 
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257) at 
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587) at
```

Gostaria só de pegar o erro específico:

```
ORA-20999: Aluno já cadastrado anteriormente
```

ou

```
Aluno já cadastrado anteriormente
```

Meu try/catch

```
try {
             ...           
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

O console está mostrando muita informação porque você está exibindo todo o stacktrace da exceção.

Ao invés disso, o que você está buscando é a mensagem detalhada da exceção, que pode ser acessada através do `getMessage()` ou `getLocalizedMessage()` caso você queira que a mensagem de erro seja localizada.

O código do erro (ORA-2099 no seu exemplo) também pode ser obtido através do `getSQLState()`.

A minha maior dúvida (especialmente lendo os comentários) e a pergunta editada é porque você quer imprimir informações da exceção através da sua página JSP. O conteúdo do JSP deve, em geral, ser composto apenas por elementos que irão compor o que é processado nos clientes.

O tratamento da exceção que você deseja ao meu ver faz parte do escopo do servidor, e seria muito mais fácil incluí-lo junto ao seu catch através de um `System.out.println()` passando como parâmetro a mensagem/causa/código e quaisquer outros detalhes da exceção que interesse a você, ou melhor ainda: usar seu Logger para imprimir conforme suas configurações l4j.

Comment: Com a getMessage() e com a getLocalizedMessage() não apareceu nada 
 e com getSQLState() deu `cannot find symbol`

Comment: Não apareceu nada no console, mas isso não significa que as mensagens estão vazias. Você ainda precisa escrever essas varáveis na sua saída padrão (terminal), que você fazia antes através do `new java.io.PrintWriter(out)`.

Existem várias formas para enviar essa mensagem pro terminal. Uma delas é usar js através do `console.log("")`, que exibirá no terminal tudo o que for passado como parâmetro.

Comment: eu tentei assim: `exception.getMessage();`

Comment: O problema do printStackTrace é que ele exibirá toda a pilha de erros, o que inclui mais informações do que você quer ver. Os métodos `getMessage()` não redirecionam a saída por padrão, ou seja, você ainda vai precisar enviar essas informações pra saída padrão do seu servidor, e existem algumas formas diferentes pra fazer isso.

Isso pode aparecer no console do client (browser) através do `console.log()`; ou no servidor usando <% out.println(exception.getMessage()) %>. 

Outra solução melhor ainda seria fazer o controle do que é exibido no console no seu método de acesso no servidor.

Comment: o controle seria mais manual?

Comment: e seu quisesse pegar só a primeira mensagem?

Comment: Essa pagina de erro, nem sempre será a mesma mensagem. que vem automaticamente, mas gostaria que mostrasse de forma amigável

Comment: Ah, só agora entendi o que você quer fazer! Você quer exibir a mensagem da exceção na sua página JSP! Bom, nesse caso eu creio que a melhor prática seria de você criar suas próprias exceções e fazê-las estender ServletException. Aí você conseguiria fazer um controle robusto de exceções e dispará-las/tratá-las corretamente.

Caso isso pareça muito trabalhoso, vale a pena fazer um teste modificando o `throw new ServletException(ex);` para `throw new ServletException(ex.getMessage());`, acredito que o construtor que você está utilizando tá engolindo a mensagem da exceção e por isso vai vazia.